# position:absolute follows other elements margin

Tags: html, css

I have a `#background` and a `#content` box. The `#background` is supposed to be at top, and `#content` box have a `margin-top` of `X` pixels.

Now, the problem is that even though `#background` have the `position: absolute;` property, it follows the `#content`s margin.

Why is the `#background` affected?

HTML

```
<div id="background"></div>

<div id="content">Content</div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    background-color: Coral;
}

#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;

    position: absolute;

    background-color: AntiqueWhite;

    z-index: -1;
}
```

Reproduced problem http://jsfiddle.net/GeU35/

Comment: Im confused by what your asking. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/GeU35/2/) You want this?

Comment: Well well... That was a small correction. Thank you

Comment: Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes. Throw an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: All done. Also NP, little mistakes but it wont happen again now you know :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just needed to set its position via `top: 0;`. Remember you can add `left: 0;` to make it sit to the left as well. Also anyway you want. `bottom: 0;` and `right: 0;`.

### CSS:

```
#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: AntiqueWhite;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/GeU35/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if I understand, but will doing this fix your issue? Ultimately setting `top: 0` and `left: 0` to `#background`

```
#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    background-color: AntiqueWhite;

    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting effect, but ultimately you have specified an absolute position, then not given any position information. I believe that's why it misbehaved. As mentioned in other answers simply setting something like top:0px solves it readily.